# How to update/reload non visible cells in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have to trigger the download processes for all cells which are all visible and non visible without scrolling the collection view. When I used to `reloadData()` it updates only visible cells, the remaining cells will update after scrolling down. Is there any way to initiate download for all the cells without scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to loop for all your links say in `viewDidLoad` and refresh in the callback with `collectionView.reloadData()` , the reason behind that in `collectionView` is optimization of not allocating hidden cells that's why there is a dequeuing

Comment: So I need to collect all the links and start download without need worry about non visible cells. right?

Comment: yesssssssssssssss and strore what you get in response in an array

Comment: But `collectionView.reloadData()` its not good idea cause it reload all the collection view and it consume performance, so it would be better if you trigger the download processes when you create the collection view and store data in array, and bind them when you scroll.